# How to load a List box with Combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, listbox

the problem with this is that it dont load it one at a time it makes a duplicate of it self

```
        private void positionIDComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if (positionIDComboBox.SelectedValue!=null)
        {
            try
            {

                contactPositionListBox.Items.Add(positionIDComboBox.SelectedValue);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.GetType().ToString());
            }
        }


    }
```

[image]

And how would i have the list box display a string value but have a value of a int  that i would add from the combobox i have tried to fill the list box datasource with values from the database but i couldnt get the combobox to populate the listbox

Comment: You need to share some sample data being displayed in combo box and list box and tell us how data should be displayed and how it is being displayed instead.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i have edited the question  i need to display the a f in the list box

Comment: As mentioned, we need to see how you are setting up the DataSource, ValueMember and DisplayMember properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to change the event to

private void contactIDComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)

Answer (score 0):

you can check before add

```
if (!contactPositionListBox.Items.Contains(positionIDComboBox.SelectedValue))
    contactPositionListBox.Items.Add(positionIDComboBox.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: it dont stop the duplicate

Answer (score 0):

For getting the text, use:

```
 contactPositionListBox.Items.Add(positionIDComboBox.Text);
```

For having an ID also, I would use a listview

```
        var lvItem = new ListViewItem(positionIDComboBox.Text);
        lvItem.Tag = positionIDComboBox.SelectedValue
        contactPositionListView.Items.Add(lvItem);
```

To stop duplicates

```
        if (!contactPositionListView.Items.Contains(lvItem))
        {
            contactPositionListView.Items.Add(lvItem);
        }
```

You can then use the Tag to get the Index from the combo

Alternatively, use a ListView and put the Id in a second column